# distance between two array movie

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a function that calculates the distance between two array movie.

**This is my DataFrame :**

```
movie_title  movieId   Action  Adventure  Fantasy  Sci-Fi Thriller
Avatar         1        1.0      1.0        1.0     1.0     0.0
Spectre        2        1.0      1.0        0.0     0.0      1  
John Carter    3        1.0      1.0        0.0     1.0     0.0
```

**then I represent movies as an array :**

```
df_array = userGenreTable.as_matrix(columns=userGenreTable.columns[2:])
```

**Output :**

```
array([[1., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

I represented the dataset as a dictionary:

```
df_2_dict = userGenreTable_2.to_dict('records')
```

so my question is **How can I calculates the distance between two array movie ?**

Comment: What metric defines "distance"? And "array movie" does not make sense, I assume you mean "movie array" in that it is an array of movie details. If that's the case, the fact that it focuses on movies is pretty much irrelevant since you just have an array of features that are either 1 or 0.

Comment: @roganjosh, yes I want to say " movie array"

Comment: to compare 2 movies, you do the euclidian distance, that is the square root of the sum of the squared differences. You can even skip the square root part to be faster. In dataframe computations, that'd be row1^2 - row2 ^2 and then sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain distance between all possible pairs in `df_array`, you need to calculate a distance matrix. Using `scipy.spatial`:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix

# p = 2 for euclidean distances 
distance_matrix(df_array, df_array, p = 2)
```